# DB2 timestampdiff function returning unexpected results

Tags: datetime, timestamp, db2, epoch, datetime-conversion

I'm using the following syntax

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(2, CHAR(CREATED - TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01 00:00:00'))
```

where `CREATED` is of type `TIMESTAMP` and the database is DB2. The intension is to get the timestamp converted to millis from epoch. If there is a better function that would be more helpful.

Sample data:
For `2011-10-04 13:54:50` returned value is `1316613290` but actual value should be `1317732890` (got from http://www.epochconverter.com)

Query to run

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(2, CHAR(TIMESTAMP('2011-10-04 13:54:50') - TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01 00:00:00'))) FROM  SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the result of the fact that `TIMESTAMPDIFF` returns an *estimate* of the difference between the timestamps, not the *actual* value, as expected.

From the [reference](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/topic/db2/rbafz.pdf), page 435 (assuming for iSeries):

> The following assumptions are used when converting the element values
>   to the requested interval type:
>
> - One year has 365 days.
> - One year has 52 weeks.
> - One year has 12 months.
> - One quarter has 3 months.
> - One month has 30 days.
> - One week has 7 days.
> - One day has 24 hours.
> - One hour has 60 minutes.
> - One minute has 60 seconds.
> - One second has 1000000 microseconds.

And the actual calculation used is:

> seconds + (minutes + (hours + ((days + (months * 30) + (years * 365)) * 24)) * 60) * 60

This is, for obvious reasons, inexact.  Not helpful.

This appears to be a direct consequence of the way the timestamp arithmetic results are returned.
That is;

```
SELECT                                                              
TIMESTAMP('1971-03-02 00:00:00') - TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01 00:00:00') 
FROM sysibm/sysdummy1
```

returns:

```
10,201,000,000.000000         

Which can be divided into:
```

- `1` year
- `02` months
- `01` days
- `00` hours
- `00` minutes
- `00` seconds
- `000000` microseconds

Which is *imprecise* period/duration information.  While there are a multitude of situations where this type of data *is* useful, this isn't one of them.

Short answer: The exact answer *cannot* be correctly calculated in the database, and in fact *should not*.

---

Long answer:

The calculations are *possible*, but rather complex, and definitely not suited for in-database calculation.  I'm not going to reproduce them here (look up [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) if you're interested, specifically the various `Chronology` subclasses).  Your biggest problem is going to be the fact that months aren't all the same length.  Also, you're going to run into major problems if your timestamps are anything other than UTC - more specifically, Daylight Savings time is going to play havoc with the calculation.  Why?  Because the offsets can change at any time, for any country.

Maybe you could explain *why* you need the number of milliseconds?  Hopefully you're using Java (or able to do so), and can use `java.time`.  But if you're on an iSeries, it's probably RPG...

Answer (score 1):

According to [the v9.7 info center](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0000861.html), TIMESTAMPDIFF returns an *estimated* time difference, based on 365 days in a year (not true ~25% of the time), 30 days in a month (not true 75% of the time, though averages out a bit better than that), 24 hours in a day (not true a couple days of the year in some timezones), 60 minutes in an hour (hooray, one right!), and 60 seconds in a minute (true >99.9% of the time - we do get leap seconds).

So, no, this is not the way to get epoch time in DB2.  Thus far, I've resorted to getting the time as a timestamp, and converting it in the client.

Answer (score 1):

Part of your error occurs because of the inaccuracy of the TIMESTAMPDIFF function, as others have pointed out.

The other source of error occurs because the Epoch is based on GMT – so you have to take your local timezone into account.

So, you can do this with the following expression:

```
(DAYS(timestamp('2011-10-04-13.54.50.000000') - current timezone) - DAYS('1970-01-01-00.00.00.000000')) * 86400 + MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(timestamp('2011-10-04-13.54.50.000000') - current timezone)
```

You can write a simple UDF to simplify this:

```
create or replace function epoch (in db2ts timestamp)
   returns bigint
   language sql
   deterministic
   no external action
   return (days(db2ts - current timezone) - days('1970-01-01-00.00.00.000000')) * 86400 + midnight_seconds(db2ts - current timezone);
```

Good luck,