# IBM i Date Diff with CYYMMDD - can't use DATE()

Tags: sql, date, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

(title edited)
Good afternoon, all!

Using IBM i version 7.1 and looking to calculate difference between two dates in a query.  Since nothing is ever easy, one date is in CYYMMDD format, the other (curdate()) is YYYY-MM-DD.  I tried to CAST my CYYMMDD formatted date (field name APENGD) as a varchar(10) then wrapped that in a CAST as a date (since decimals can't be CASTed as dates):

```
Cast(Cast(APENGD + 19000000 As varchar(10)) As date) As math
```

but I only see a result `++++++++++++++` for whatever reason.  I was able to test a few different versions of this and found I can't use DATE anywhere...can anyone suggest an alternative??

Thanks in advance!

Matt

Comment: How are you planning on calculating the difference on DB2?  There aren't any good built-in functions I'm aware of, and [`TIMESTAMPDIFF` is almost useless](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677529/db2-timestampdiff-function-returning-unexpected-results).(because of the preceding date math).  Additionally, using a difference between columns often results in indices being ignored (because it requires per-row-evaluation info) - what are you planning to do with the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

casting varchar to date only works when the string includes separators.

At 7.1 you could use `TIMESTAMP_FORMAT()`, but you'd end up with a timestamp instead of just a date.  But that's easily dealt with.

```
Date(Timestamp_format(char(APENGD + 19000000),'YYYYMMDD')) As math
```

My prefered solution when dealing with numeric/character value dates is creating a User Defined Function to handle conversion.

You could write your own, or use the one I do.  [iDate](http://www.think400.dk/downloads.htm) written by Alan Campin.  Then your code would simple be:

```
   idate(APENGD,'*CYMD') as nath
```

Note that if you're trying to use date differences in a `WHERE` clause, like so

```
WHERE CURRENT_DATE - 3 months <= idate(APENGD,'*CYMD')
```

The above will perform poorly since an existing index over APENGD can't be used (directly).  Assuming a recent(6.1+) version of the OS, you can create a new index that includes the expression you're using to convert APENGD to date.

Or you could code it using the Date->Numeric function `ConvertToIdate` that Alan helpfully includes.  That would allow existing indexes to be used.

```
WHERE ConvertToiDate(CURRENT_DATE - 3 months,'*CYMD') <= APENGD
```

Comment: Thank you, Charles!  the TIMESTAMP_FORMAT solution works perfectly.

Comment: The WHERE clause might be made to perform better with an INDEX over an _expression_ that converts APENGD to a DATE form. Since i 6.1, _expressions_ are allowed for INDEXes. Take experimenting to figure a good one.

Answer (score 1):

The DDL was not offered [to define the column APENGD].  No matter, as the following should suffice, mostly irrespective the definition; either as a string or as a zero-scale numeric.  The effect depends on the SQL recognition of a 14-character [up to 26-character, since some v7 release] character-string as an unformatted [i.e. lacking any delimiters, thus digits-only] TIMESTAMP representation:

```
date(timestamp((APENGD + 19000000) concat '000000'))
```

[IBM i 7.3->Database->Reference->SQL reference->Language elements->Data types->Datetime values->String representations of datetime values->Timestamp strings](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafztsstrings.htm)

> A string representation of a timestamp is a character or a Unicode graphic string that starts with a digit and has a length of at least 14 characters. …

Answer (score 0):

If you want calculate difference between 2 dates, you can use:

```
`TIMESTAMPDIFF(32, cast(MYTIMESTAMP1 - MYTIMESTAMP2 as char(22)))`
```

The first argument of function specify the type of result.

1 : millisecond
16 : days
2 : second 
32 : week
4 : minutes 
64 : month
8 : hour 
128 : trimester
256 : Year

Comment: Please, never use `TIMESTAMPDIFF` (or really, the timestamp subtraction):  It calculates results based off of estimates, which will throw results off when you least expect it, as [I explain here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677529/db2-timestampdiff-function-returning-unexpected-results).

Comment: i dont knew that, thak you ;)