# How to get difference from two timestamp in DB2?

Tags: sql, db2

i have a requirement in which i have to get time difference of two timestamp in hours and than later find an average of the hours.

i am using below query to find difference of two timestamp but it does not give exact result it gives approx result. do we have any other solution to achieve the same.My two time stamps are as( LAST_MODIFIED_DATETIME - 2016-11-30 15:39:01.131      CREATE_DATETIME - 2016-07-01 17:25:52.375)

```
select timestampdiff(8, char(LAST_MODIFIED_DATETIME-CREATE_DATETIME)) as total_time from test_table where name='some name';
```

Comment: yes timestampdiff is approx

Comment: @Hogan - do we have anyother solution to achieve same with exact result

Comment: sure... use JULIAN_DAY() on both to find the difference in days then adjust for the hour difference in the two timestamps

Comment: Have you read the entry at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677529/db2-timestampdiff-function-returning-unexpected-results] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy, by converting the timestamp to hours as follows:

```
(24*DAYS(last_modified_datetime)+MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(last_modified_datetime)/3600)
-
(24*DAYS(create_datetime)+MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(create_datetime)/3600)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the built-in Db2 function `HOURS_BETWEEN()`

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061478.html