# SQL query performance improvement for WITH query in DB2

Tags: sql, performance, db2

My query given in example is running very slow. I have closed to 4 million records in `my_task` table.

> Can we do any sort of performance improvement on this ?

Take an example to following table,

Here i have placed numbers `start_dt` and `end_dt` instead of putting `timestamp` format.

Additional note where there is empty `end_dt` means its an active record and being worked on by worker.

```
T_ID |start_dt |end_dt |code       |p_id
-----|---------|-------|-----------|---
1    |8        |4      |INPROGRESS |110
1    |4        |       |ASSIGNED   |110
4    |10       |4      |INPROGRESS |110
4    |4        |       |ASSIGNED   |110
5    |4        |4      |INPROGRESS |110
6    |12       |12     |INPROGRESS |110
6    |8        |8      |ASSIGNED   |110
6    |8        |       |DONE       |110
2    |12       |12     |INPROGRESS |210
2    |8        |8      |ASSIGNED   |210
2    |8        |       |DONE       |210
3    |12       |12     |INPROGRESS |111
```

output looks like,

```
P_ID |avg_bgn_diff |assigned |in_progress |completed | comp_diff
-----|-------------|---------|------------|----------|----------
110  | 4           |   2     |    1       |     1    |      10
210  | null        |   0     |    0       |     1    |      8
111  | null        |   0     |    1       |     0    |      null
```

**Output explained:** I have masked the original query with fictional names table ref can be broken I apologize in advance for that.

- MY_TASK table has unique T_ID
- MY_PEOPLE table is employee table
- MY_TASK_REF table hold detail about who has what task
- TASK has status as each status change operation results into record craeted in task table. Statues such as ASSIGNED, INPROGRESS, and DONE
- Now Wherever END_DT is not present represents active record
- First output field `avg_bgn_diff` we just want to find average time for all (mean END_DT is null) 'ASSIGNED' task
- This out fields `assigned |in_progress |completed` represent each employee has how many active task in each category.
- Find average `comp_diff` completion time for each employee. When record came into INPROGRESS then employee started working on. And we do average of task which completed with status DONE today. We get start date of INPROGRESS and start date of DONE.

I have following query,

```
WITH a AS (
    SELECT
        t1.t_id AS t_id,
        t1.start_dt AS start_dt,
        t1.end_dt AS end_dt,
        t1.code AS code,
        t2.p_id AS p_id
    FROM
        my_task t2
        INNER JOIN my_task_ref t1 ON t1.t_id = t2.t_id
        INNER JOIN my_people p1 ON t2.p_id = p1.p_id
    WHERE
        -- ignore DONE tasks
        t1.t_id NOT IN (
            SELECT t.t_id
            FROM my_task t
            WHERE t.code = 'DONE' AND trunc(t.execution_dt) < trunc(current_timestamp)
        )
        and p1.department_id = '1234' 
    ORDER BY p_id DESC
) SELECT
    d.p_id,
    d.avg_bgn_diff
    ,e.assigned
    ,e.in_progress
    ,e.completed
    ,g.comp_diff
  FROM
  `-- find average time for persons for diff ASSIGNMENT
    (
        SELECT c.p_id,AVG(c.bgn_diff) AS avg_bgn_diff
        FROM(
                SELECT b.p_id,timestampdiff(4,current_timestamp - a.start_dt) AS bgn_diff
                FROM ( SELECT p_id,t_id,start_dt FROM a WHERE end_dt IS NULL ) b
                LEFT OUTER JOIN  ( SELECT p_id, t_id,start_dt FROM a WHERE 
                     code = 'ASSIGNED' AND   end_dt IS NULL ) x ON x.p_id = b.p_id
            ) c  GROUP BY C.p_id
    ) d
    -- find count of each codes person has
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT 
            p_id,
            SUM( CASE WHEN code = 'ASSIGNED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS assigned,
            SUM( CASE WHEN code = 'INPROGRESS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS in_progress,
            SUM( CASE WHEN code = 'DONE' AND trunc(start_dt) = trunc(current_timestamp)
                    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS completed
        FROM
            a where end_dt IS NULL
        GROUP BY p_id
    ) e on D.p_id=E.p_id 
    -- find total avg diff of entire task took to compelete.
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT F.p_id,AVG(f.bgn_diff) AS comp_diff
        FROM
            (
                SELECT a.p_id, timestampdiff(4,b.start_dt - a.start_dt) AS bgn_diff
                FROM (
                        SELECT p_id, t_id, start_dt FROM a WHERE code = 'INPROGRESS'
                    ) a
                    INNER JOIN (
                        SELECT p_id, t_id, start_dt FROM a
                        WHERE code = 'DONE' AND   trunc(start_dt) = trunc(current_timestamp)
                    ) b ON a.t_id = b.t_id
            ) f GROUP BY F.p_id
    ) g ON D.p_id=G.p_id
WITH
ur;
```

Can we write this in different way which can improve the performance ?

**Note:** Indexes are present in all necessary columns.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For starters, try replacing NOT IN with a left join

Comment: @DanielMarcus I have that in my mind. Any other changes  ?

Comment: why do you have so many nested queries? i feel like alot of those could be rewritten with left joins as well - at the end for example, you are selecting from table 'a' three times and you should be able to do one select and use conditional logic if needed

Comment: @DanielMarcus I thought for while but didn't came up just one whole query with left joins. If you can demonstrate just `find average time for persons for diff ASSIGNMENT` writing this part as an example for me ?

Comment: please explain how your data set matches the result of your query - im seeing what seems to be alot of inconsistancies

Comment: @DanielMarcus My sql has this operation `timestampdiff(4,current_timestamp - a.start_dt)` I have used just numbers for simple understanding.

Comment: ...note that `TIMESTAMPDIFF` is an estimate, and over some durations will return incorrect results (it assumes that months are 30 days long, for example).

Comment: Also, what version of DB2?  You may be able to use windowing functions, which would probably knock down your subquery count to 1.

Comment: Sorry, also, what platform - iSeries, LUW, etc.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse what does this mean `iSeries, LUW` ?

Comment: What OS/system are you running DB2 on?  There's 3 main 'groups' of DB2, each with their own set of capabilities - iSeries, LUW (Linux, Unix, Windows), and zOS.  Most likely would normally be LUW, but 8.x is _old_ (support ended 2009).  iSeries might be up to 8 by now, I suppose.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse DB2 version DB2 v10.5.0.4 and platform is windows servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could certainly do better if you provided a query `EXPLAIN` plan, a list of indices, and perhaps a better explanation of what it is you're trying to do (and correcting the syntax error for table reference `c`), but this version of the query may be able to speed things up a bit.

Please note the comments throughout!

```
WITH Incomplete_Task AS (SELECT My_Task_Ref.t_id,
                                My_Task_Ref.start_dt, My_Task_Ref.end_dt,
                                My_Task_Ref.code,
                                Task_A.p_id
                         FROM My_Task AS Task_A
                         JOIN My_Task_Ref
                           ON My_Task_Ref.t_id = Task_A.t_id
                         JOIN My_People
                           ON My_People.p_id = My_Task_Ref.p_id
                              AND My_People.department_id = '1234'
                         -- NOT IN should be fine, I just default to NOT EXISTS
                         WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                           FROM My_Task AS Task_B
                                           WHERE Task_B.t_id = Task_A.t_id
                                           AND Task_B.code = 'DONE'
                                           -- Calling a function on a column can 
                                           -- cause indices to be ignored
                                           AND Task_B.execution_dt < TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE)))

SELECT Average_Time_And_Code_Count.p_id,
       Average_Time_And_Code_Count.average_begin_difference,
       COALESCE(Average_Time_And_Code_Count.assigned, 0),
       COALESCE(Average_Time_And_Code_Count.in_progress, 0),
       COALESCE(Average_Time_And_Code_Count.completed, 0),
       Average_Complete_Time.average_complete_difference
FROM (SELECT p_id,
             -- The join you had previously was almost certainly duplicating 
             -- some rows, distorting the results.
             AVG(CASE WHEN code = 'ASSIGNED' 
                      -- TIMESTAMPDIFF works off an estimate, and will be wrong
                      -- if a task takes more than a month.
                      THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(4, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - A.start_dt) END) AS average_begin_difference,
             SUM(CASE WHEN code = 'ASSIGNED' 
                               THEN 1 END) AS assigned,
             SUM(CASE WHEN code = 'INPROGRESS' 
                               THEN 1 END) AS in_progress,
             SUM(CASE WHEN code = 'DONE' 
                                    AND start_dt >= TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE) 
                               THEN 1 END) AS completed
      FROM Filtered_Task
      WHERE end_dt IS NULL
      GROUP BY p_id) AS Average_Time_And_Code_Count
-- I'm not convinced this measures what you think it does,
-- but I'm not sure what it is you think you _are_ measuring....
LEFT JOIN (SELECT p_id, TIMESTAMPDIFF(4, Done.start_dt - InProgress.start_dt) AS average_complete_difference
           FROM Filtered_Task AS InProgress
           JOIN Filtered_Task AS Done
             ON InProgress.t_id = Done.t_id
                AND Done.code = 'DONE'
                AND Done.start_dt >= TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE)
           WHERE InProgress.code = 'INPROGRESS') AS Average_Complete_Time
       ON Average_Complete_Time.p_id = Averate_Time_And_Code_Count.p_id
```

Comment: @Clockwork-Mouse I have added detailed explanation for output.

Comment: `TIMESTAMPDIFF works off an estimate, and will be wrong if a task takes more than a month.` What's a solution for this one ?

Comment: @JBaba - I'm going to redirect you [to this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40894634/how-to-get-difference-from-two-timestamp-in-db2).  That one covers hours, but you should be able to convert it to minutes.  Note that the two timestamps **MUST** be in the same timezone, and **MUST** be in one without DST, or you're going to have to do a lot of extra, complicated math first.  Personally, I'd recommend creating a function that wraps up the math for you - `TIMESTAMP_DIFF(unit, start, end)`.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the ORDER BY p_id DESC in the first query, typically ORDER BY is very expensive. Also in the first query the NOT IN appears to be looking at the same base table  my_task, so I would suggest just putting in the filter right in the WHERE clause.

```
WITH a AS (
SELECT
    t1.t_id AS t_id,
    t1.start_dt AS start_dt,
    t1.end_dt AS end_dt,
    t1.code AS code,
    t2.p_id AS p_id
FROM
    my_task t2
    INNER JOIN my_task_ref t1 ON t1.t_id = t2.t_id
    INNER JOIN my_people p1 ON t2.p_id = p1.p_id
WHERE
    -- ignore DONE tasks
    t2.code <> 'DONE' AND trunc(t2.execution_dt) < trunc(current_timestamp)
    and p1.department_id = '1234' )
```

Also, it would be good to try to reduce the depth/number of sub-queries.
So something like

```
 SELECT c.p_id,AVG(c.bgn_diff) AS avg_bgn_diff
    FROM(
            SELECT b.p_id,timestampdiff(4,current_timestamp - a.start_dt) AS bgn_diff
            FROM ( SELECT p_id,t_id,start_dt FROM a WHERE end_dt IS NULL ) b
            LEFT OUTER JOIN  ( SELECT p_id, t_id,start_dt FROM a WHERE 
                 code = 'ASSIGNED' AND   end_dt IS NULL ) x ON x.p_id = b.p_id
        ) c  GROUP BY C.p_id
```

could become...

```
SELECT a.p_id,AVG(timestampdiff(4,current_timestamp - a.start_dt)) AS 
avg_bgn_diff
FROM a
WHERE end_dt IS NULL OR (code = 'ASSIGNED' AND end_dt IS NULL )
GROUP BY a.p_id
```

Comment: your suggestion 1 is not possible because I want to remove all the task records which is completed and less then `current_timestamp`. While your suggestion only removes `DONE`  records not all.

Comment: @JBaba if you "want" something describe it in your question and do not let people guess - if you forget to specify something it is not the fault of somebody trying to help you!