# Calculate SQL db2 date time difference between below

Tags: sql, date, types, db2, rdbms

I have dates column in format like below 2020-06-08 03:54 , 2020-06-08 04:10

I want to calculate time difference between this in SQL dB please
Sample excel data
Definition
Time_cmp= R_date - p_date

R_date         | p_ date | time_cmp
2020-06-08 03:54 | 2020-06-08 04:10 | 16

Comment: You can use **Datediff**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get difference from two timestamp in DB2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40894634/how-to-get-difference-from-two-timestamp-in-db2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of these Db2 functions

```
DAYS_BETWEEN    (h,l)
HOURS_BETWEEN   (h,l)
MINUTES_BETWEEN (h,l)
MONTHS_BETWEEN  (h,l)
SECONDS_BETWEEN (h,l)
WEEKS_BETWEEN   (h,l)
YEARS_BETWEEN   (h,l)
YMD_BETWEEN     (h,l)
```

The functions return whole numbers. Put the higher value first to get a +ve number out.